# R: Properly using a dataframe as an argument to a function

Tags: r, function

I am practicing using the apply function in R, and so I'm writing a simple function to apply to a dataframe.

I have a dataframe with 2 columns.

```
 V1    V2
 1     3
 2     4
```

I decided to do some basic arithmetic and have the answer in the 3rd column, specifically, I want to multiply the first column by 2 and the second column by 3, then sum them.

```
 V1    V2    V3
 1     3     11
 2     4     16
```

Here's what I was thinking:

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:4),ncol=2,nrow=2))
some_function <- function(some_df) {some_df[,1]*2 +   
                                    some_df[,2]*3}
mydf <- apply(mydf ,2, some_function)
```

But what is wrong with my arguments to the function?  R is giving me an error regarding the dimension of the dataframe.  Why?

Comment: Did you chose multiplication as an example or is it your actual task?

Comment: it was just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things wrong:

1) apply "loops" a vector of either each column or row, so you just address the name [1] not [,1]
2) you need to run by row MARGIN=1, not 2
3) you need to cbind the result, because apply doesn't append, so you're overwriting the vector

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:4),ncol=2,nrow=2))

some_function <- function(some_df) {some_df[1]*2 +   
                                      some_df[2]*3}

mydf <- cbind(mydf,V3=apply(mydf ,1, some_function))

#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  3 11
#2  2  4 16
```

but probably easier just to do the vector math:

```
mydf$V3<-mydf[,1]*2 + mydf[,2]*3
```

because vector math is one of the greatest things about R